# Issue with named routes for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-resources

I have a rails 3 nested resource defined as follows

```
resources :candidates do
  collection do
    get :bookmarked
  end
  resources :bookmarks, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

The bookmarked action in the candidats collection will create a new bookmark for the candidate. This works fine as expected.

The problem arises when I try to delete a bookmark.

I have a link in my candidate show page as follows

```
<%= link_to "Remove bookmark", candidate_bookmarks_path(@candidate, @bookmark), :method => :delete %>
```

When I click on this link I get the following error

```
No route matches "/candidates/1/bookmarks.8"
```

I was expecting the url to be /candidates/1/bookmarks/8 not what is printed in the error. I was also expecting the request to be directed to the bookmarks controllers destroy method. But clearly that is not happening.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for destroy action should be `candidate_bookmark_path(@candidate, @bookmark)` instead of `candidate_bookmarks_path(@candidate, @bookmark)`.

Just remember, you are deleting a specific bookmark of a specific candidate, so the resources should be singular in your path, and you need to pass specific object for each resource.